# xml annotation which can stop an attribute to being converted into an xml string

Tags: java, xml, annotations

I have an attribute 'abc'in a class. I want to restrict this attrbute to being converted into an XML String format.
Is there any XMl Annotation which i can use on the attribute, to avoid this being converted into the XML String?

Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use @XmlTransient annotation.
For more information vist the [@XmlTransient Sample](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/jaxbs-xmltransient-and-property-order.html)
Below is example for avoiding "password" attribute in XML conversion in JAXB.So it is annotated with
@XmlTransient annotation

```
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

   @XmlRootElement
   @XmlType(propOrder = { "phoneNumbers", "name"})
   public class Customer extends Person {

   private String password;
   private List<String> phoneNumbers;

   @XmlTransient
   public String getPassword() {
        return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

  @XmlElement(name = "phone-number")
  public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
    return phoneNumbers;
  }

  public void setPhoneNumbers(List<String> phoneNumbers) {
    this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
  }


 }   
 /* demo class*/ 
  public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

         Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
         File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
   }

  }  


  /*Generated xml doesn't have password tag */  
  /* <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
     <customer>  
        <id>123</id>
        <phone-number>555-1111</phone-number>
        <phone-number>555-2222</phone-number>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
     </customer>  
  */
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options when excluding a property when you are using a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation to process your XML.

**Option #1 - `@XmlTransient`**

The most common way to exclude a field/property is to annotate it with `@XmlTransient`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlTransient
    private String foo;

    private String bar;

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Option #2 - `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`**

If you want to exclude more than half of the properties I recommend setting `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` on your class.  Then only annotated fields/properties will be mapped.  In the example below we don't have to exclude foo, but be have to specifically include bar.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Root {

    private String foo;

    @XmlElement
    private String bar;

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Option #3 - transient**

If you are using field access then you can also simply mark the field as transient to exclude it.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    private transient String foo;

    private String bar;

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

---

**Demo**

The following demo code can be used regardless of which option you choose.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setFoo("FOO");
        root.setBar("BAR");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

In the output we see that the `foo` element is excluded from the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <bar>BAR</bar>
</root>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [@XMLTransient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html)?

Comment: Could you please elobrate, what this will do and how to use this?

Comment: Well it will tell JaxB or whatever implementation you're using to skip the attribute when transforming the Java object. To use it: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/jaxbs-xmltransient-and-property-order.html as @Prabhaker suggests

Answer (score 1):

@XmlTransient prevents an attribute being converted to xml